# How to repair a black screen after windows11 update crush?

Tags: windows, screen, updates, freeze, crush

After accepting to restart my pc (lenovo thinkpad i5 8th generation) for a windows 11 update, my pc restarted and I’ve could hear the sound pf windows start but nothing on the screen (dark screen).

I tried to force shutdown several times and I’ve could at a certain point see a frozen cursor with a reload icon and only my background picture. Cursor, pen, tactile and keyboard, none respond so i couldn’t enter the safe mode but by analyzing in the bios the hardware is not the problem.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix it , please ? i don’t want to formate it and loose my files.